# Reference for Hecke theory on meromorphic modular forms

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Is there any good reference for meromorphic modular forms (or weakly holomorphic modular forms), especially about Hecke theory? Also, I want to know about explicit examples of "Hecke eigenforms" which are meromorphic. Now I'm reading [Guerzhoy's paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2008-136-09/S0002-9939-08-09277-0/S0002-9939-08-09277-0.pdf) but this is insufficient for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest *The 1-2-3 of Modular Forms* by D.Zagier.